# Javascript - TypeError: x is not a function at done

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am building my own browserside javascript sdk, using webpack and node.

I have built a async/await document function, which simply submits a document to an api.

This function could be called twice in the browser (if there is a second image) However on the second document function call i get the following error.

> TypeError: hsp.document is not a function
>       at done

**index.html**

```
<script>

hsp = new HSP();

// function called on button click
async function done() {

    try {
         const doc = await hsp.document(transaction, token, url, this.frontBase64);

        console.log(doc);

        // If second image,  submit it also.
        if(this.backBase64) {
            const doc = await hsp.document(transaction, token, url, this.backBase64);

        }

    } catch (er) {
        console.log(er);
    }

}

</script>
```

**sdk.js**

```
async document(transaction, token, url, doc) {

        try {

            this.document = await this.api.submitDocument(transaction,
                token, url, doc);

            if (this.document.response.status !== 200) {

                return {
                    "success": false,
                    "response": this.document
                };

            }

            return {
                "success": true,
                "response": this.document
            };


        } catch (e) {
            return {
                "success": false,
                "response": e
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: `token, url this.frontBase64);` doesn't look like valid syntax

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges thank you, i forgot i was setting this.document so the function document was not there anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `document` function is defined in your HSP object.

When calling it a first time, by doing `hsp.document`, it's executed and inside the function, the this keyword is a reference to the hsp instance you invoked the `document` function from.

Inside your function, you're reaffecting the field `this.document` in your document function, with whatever is returned by the `this.api.submitDocument` call. So, it's not a function anymore after the first function call.

Comment: thanks, this worked. Have to be careful in future when setting this.x to ensure there is no function name called x